# Broken link to theme asset after restoring backup

Tags: themes, backup

Restoring site's backup, results in not loading sites asset e.g. style.css and .js files.
I checked the site and notice the link to theme asset:

```
site.com%20/wp-content/themes/themename/style.css
```

as you can see, the `%20` after the domain is cause the problem. The link above generated from bottom code in functions.php:

```
 wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

I checked Site URL in wp settings and it's Ok, also links in functions.php are Ok.
So where should I go from here ? Where that extra **%20** came from ?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that %20 is the URL-encoding of a space, so make sure that there is no trailing whitespace in the URL too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your wordpress db table wp_options and from there check option name : siteUrl and home url and change %20 from there.

Comment: Ah...that was the problem and now it solved with your help ImSarah. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @startToday NP.. Happy you solvrd your problem.. :)